# Rails & Postgres: Best practice for many boolean relationship entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, query-performance

I'm looking for input on what's best practice for my problem. In abstract terms, I need to store a lot of relationships and need to prioritise between database size, query speed and “ease of maintenance”. The setup is Ruby on Rails with PostgreSQL.

**More specific description:** Imagine a website that's essentially a searchable database of `Products` sold by `Vendors`. `Vendors` may not ship worldwide, and I want to filter out `Products` by Vendors who won't ship to a user based on their GeoIP country. To make matters slightly more complex, a `Product` page can have two different features (let’s call them F1 and F2) that are separately geo-IP-dependent.

**Example:** A `Vendor` may want their `Product` pages to have feature F1 for all countries worldwide except a few e.g. because of embargos; but feature F2 may only be available for countries within e.g. Europe.

Country filters will always be set at the `Vendor` level.

The “search” function of the website is a basic SQL search in which I want `Products` to show up if at least one of the features is available for the current user’s country.

The website will allow in the range of 1,000 to 3,000 `Vendors` (this is a hard limit), and a total of around 10,000 to 50,000 `Products`. Let's assume that in the beginning, filtering is only relevant to around 100 `Vendors`.

**I had the following ideas and hope that others have feedback on these, or additional approaches:**

1. One relation model `CountryVendor` with two boolean columns (in which case optionally, a Product could still be shown if the respective `country_vendor` does not yet exist; i.e. show if `!country_vendor&.allow`).

   Assuming ca. 200 countries, this would imply ca. 2,000 rows in the beginning, and around 600k rows if filters were in place for every one of the 3,000 potential `Vendors`.

   (Theoretically, if non-existence is treatet as `true`, I could also set up a rake task that removes rows that are `false` for both features, thus reigning in the table size.)
2. Two relation models `CountryVendorF1` and `CountryVendorF2`, each with just one boolean column. Not sure if this will effectively be much different, but I imagine it closer to how I think of the UI for setting up the country filters (without going into detail here).
3. Two JSON columns in the `Vendors` table that would store true/false for each `Country`. (Maybe with an ISO code string as the index for simplicity.) There wouldn’t be thousands of new rows, although the DB would still grow in size, but querying might become slow.

Comment: You're assuming that a vendor has to have all 200 in the join table for every country. They don't. You just need records for the countries where they are actually available. If you want to check where they are available you do a left join. No rows - no availability.

Comment: Actually I expect this to be very mixed, but learning towards ~75% of countries for the first feature, and ~50% of countries for the second feature.

Comment: how to follow this question? I am intrigued about the possible discussion.